# Send mail to user only once when specific check box is selected and updated from profile meta updated by admin

Tags: user-meta, email, profiles

Here i have created one checkbox in admin of the wordpress and when i check and update it send mail to user it works but its sends mail every time when any part of profile is updated.Is there a way to send mail only once?

Also here i have list of property when user request for any it shows entry in backend and when admin approves it should sent email for every pdf approval by user.so when admin
approves any pdf it notifies user.But at this moment it does not happen.it fires email every time when i update profile.

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_extra_profile' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'add_extra_profile' );
function add_extra_profile(){
 global $pagenow;       
    if($pagenow == 'profile.php'){
       $us_id = get_current_user_id();
    }
    else{
     $us_id = $_GET['user_id'];
    }

$deal_meta = get_user_meta($us_id, '_userdeal'); 
$boro_meta = get_user_meta($us_id, '_borrowerdata');
$boro_status = get_user_meta($us_id, '_userformstatus');
$termsheet_meta = get_user_meta($us_id, '_usertermsheet');
$approve_termsheet_meta= get_user_meta($us_id, '_approvaltermsheet');  



$get_boro =unserialize(base64_decode($boro_meta[0]));
/*----------Termsheet Form------------------*/
$expd= explode(",",$termsheet_meta[0]);

if(!empty($termsheet_meta[0])){
echo "<table border='1' >";    
echo "<tbody><tr><th style='padding:10px;'><label>List Of Termsheet Applied For</label></th>
                <th style='padding:10px;'><label>Approval<label></th>    
            </tr>";
echo "<tr>";
for($i=0;$i<count($expd);$i++):
 $post_d = get_post($expd[$i]); 
 $title = $post_d->post_title;


echo "<td style='padding:10px;'><a href=".get_permalink($expd[$i] ).">".$title."</a></td>
        <td style='padding:10px;' >";
    if(!empty($approve_termsheet_meta[0]) &&in_array($expd[$i],$approve_termsheet_meta[0])){ 
    echo "<input type='checkbox'  name='approve_termsheet[]' value=".$expd[$i]."  checked />";
    }
    else{
     echo "<input type='checkbox'  name='approve_termsheet[]' value=".$expd[$i]."  />";
    }
echo "</td>";
    if( $i % 1== 0 ) {
    echo "</tr><tr>";
  }   

endfor;

echo "</tr>";
echo "</tbody>";    
echo "</table>";

//print_r($_REQUEST['approve_termsheet']);  
$user_info = get_userdata($us_id );
$subject = 'User Approval';
$to=$user_info->user_email;    
$body = "Your Property Termsheet is Appoved For Download.</br> You Can Login And Download It" ;
add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html"; '));

$mailSent = get_user_meta($us_id, 'mail_sent', true);

if($mailSent){
    update_user_meta($us_id, 'mail_sent', 'mail sent');
}else{
    $borrower_mail=wp_mail($to, $subject, $body);
}    


}
```

Comment: You can add user_meta first time when you send the mail and check if the user_meta is exist for that user then skip mail sending functionality

Answer (score 1):

Please add following condition.

```
$mailSent = get_user_meta($us_id, 'mail_sent', true);
if($mailSent){
    update_user_meta($us_id, 'mail_sent', 'mail sent');
}else{
    $borrower_mail=wp_mail($to, $subject, $body);
}
```

Comment: i have some list of post with checkbox and when admin check yes and save them it should notifiy the user.How its possbile?